# No 'reference error' seen when I use 'this' to access a undeclared variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome

When I type the following in Chrome Debug Console:

```
console.log('The value of this.undeclared_var = ', this.undeclared_var);
console.log('The value of undeclared_var = ', undeclared_var);
```

I see the following:

```
The value of this.undeclared_var =  undefined
VM136:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: undeclared_var is not defined
    at <anonymous>:2:47
(anonymous) @ VM136:2
```

I was expecting to see the ReferenceError for 'this.undeclared_var' too. Can somebody explain why I am not seeing reference error in the first case?

Comment: Because `this.xyz` is not an undeclared *variable*, it's just a non-existent *property*.

Comment: `this.xyz`  (  `xyz` )  is not a variable it is a property on whatever `this` is pointing to. If you wish to have `this.undeclared_var` throw errors when undeclared_var is not existing on `this` you can use the get trap in the `Proxy` api to handle such issues